# Invalid cursor state - pdo_odbc FreeTDS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds, pdo-odbc

We're running a completely nonchalant query and are getting the following error:

```
PDOException : SQLSTATE[24000]: Invalid cursor state: 0 [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid cursor state (SQLExecute[0] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.5.13/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254)
```

From PHP we're using the `pdo_odbc` library to connect via FreeTDS to SQLServer 2008

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Sorry @Raptor I submitted the question without my answer as I'd intended. I'd say that the code is relatively irrelevant in this given situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It transpires that it was the preceding query that was causing problems. We were using:

```
$pdo_statement->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to get out a single row but not doing anything with it after then. This was leaving a cursor open which was then throwing the error then next time any query was executed. For us, closing the cursor before the next query was the way forward.

```
$pdo_statement->closeCursor();
```

It's also worth noting that using `fetchAll()` (in the preceding query) is also a fix as this does not leave a cursor open.

```
$pdo_statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```